# PowerShell How to attach a vswitch to virtual machine

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to attach a virtual switch to a virtual machine on Hyper-v by using following command

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapter -vmName 'XYZ' -SwitchName 'PrimarySwitch'
```

I have two switches on Hyper-v with the same switch name `'PrimarySwitch'` so it fails because it finds two virtual switches with the same name.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have 2x switches named the same!

I don't think there is an easy work around to this. You can get other details about the switches like there ID using this:

```
Get-VMSwitch | SELECT Id, Name, NetAdapterInterfaceDescription
```

However adding the switch to a VM will only accept it's name value, not the ID. As the documentation states if the name isn't unique this will fail.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848564.aspx

In short, you **need** to rename one of your switches. This is easy enough to do in the Hyper-V manager GUI under Virtual Switch Manager. Using:

```
Rename-VMSwitch -Name "PrimarySwitch" –NewName "SecondarySwitch"
```

... Won't work because of the same name uniqueness problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition , if you can identify the switches with ID , you can try command '' (replace the ID and VM name as you need):

```
Get-VMSwitch -Id c16acc5e-d668-4fbc-84e7-9fb180380fa4 | Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName replicatest -name xxx
```

The parameter '-name' is adapter name of that VM , it you want to connect that VM's all NICs to that Vswitch , remove '-name' parameter .